# CMake External Project: put the EP in its own folder

Tags: c++, cmake

### Problem statement

I have the following project structure (assume `src` and `test` contain the obvious files):

```
.
+- src/
+- test/
+- build/
+- CMakeLists.txt
```

And I want to use Google Test for my testing. Following [instructions from Google Test README](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md) I created a `CMakeLists.txt.in` file and added the CMake code they suggest. After generating the project, I get the following project folders:

```
.
+- src/
+- googletest-download/
+- googletest-build/
+- googletest-src/
+- test/
+- build/
+- CMakeLists.txt
```

However, what I want is:

```
.
+- src/
+- googletest/
|  +- googletest-download/
|  +- googletest-build/
|  +- googletest-src/
+- test/
+- build/
+- CMakeLists.txt
```

So I modified the CMakeLists files to reflect that (see the next section for the full code). The problems that arise are:

- googletest-download is still being created
- CMake either exists with code 1 or loops in after `Detecting CXX compile features` step and, of course, nothing gets generated.
- It also says something about the `build` directory not having a CMakeLists.txt file (note that I am doing `cd build` then `cmake -G "generator_of_choice" ..`)
- as a side problem (that also happened before I made any changes), CMake issues a warning about cmake_minimum_required, despite the command being present as you will see (dunno if related).

Is there some error I overlooked (I am still relatively new to CMake)? How can I get the Google Test external project live inside its own folder so everything is tidy?

### The CMake scripts

CMakeLists.txt.in

```
project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  DOWNLOAD_DIR      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/googletest-download"
  SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/googletest-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/googletest-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR) # for some reason CMake doesn't recognize it??

project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

## GTest start ##
# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/googletest-src
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/googletest-build
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# The gtest/gtest_main targets carry header search path
# dependencies automatically when using CMake 2.8.11 or
# later. Otherwise we have to add them here ourselves.
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
  include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()
## GTest end ##

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Comment: It seems you are confused with meaning of `CMakeLists.txt` generated from `.in` file. Exactly this file should be processed by `execute_process` in the main `CMakeLists.txt`. You generate the file under `googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt` but use **different directory** as WORKING_DIRECTORY (`googletest/googletest-download`). As for "CMake issues a warning about cmake_minimum_required, despite the command being present as you will see" - Your `CMakeLists.txt.in` actually lacks for call to `cmake_minimum_required`.

Comment: Hint about better problem statement: Do not try to *describe* the error you got. Instead, **copy paste the error message** into the question post with all surrounding messages. Your project involves **three** `CMakeLists.txt`: the main one, the one generated from `CMakeLists.txt.in` and the one in the googletest project. Currently we can only *guess*  which `CMakeLists.txt` causes the errors you describe. But with **precise error messages** this would be easier to catch.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I solved it thanks to your comment on the `execute_process` command. And, thanks for pointing out the `cmake_minimum_required` issue, I definitively didn't know `CMakeLists.txt.in` needed it!